Touch events are not passing through to the system
Everything worked fine on Android 11, but I encountered difficulties on Android 12.
I can't seem to make the touch events pass through the window to the system. Through logcat, I found out that the system is setting the FLAG_SLIPPERY flag on my window, which prevents touch events from passing through to the system.
As I understand it, this is a security flag, but I haven't found a way to disable this flag.
On the Realme 6 pro (Android 11), everything works fine, but on the Motorola Edge 30 (Android 12), it doesn't.
canvasLayoutParams_vi = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

canvasLayoutParams_vi.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START;
canvasLayoutParams_vi.x = 0;
canvasLayoutParams_vi.y = 0;

vi = new EmptyView(this);
windowManager.addView(vi, canvasLayoutParams_vi);

The error itself:
Letterbox_left_ActivityRecord{606481 u0 com.MyApp/.MainActivity t377} has FLAG_SLIPPERY. Please report this in b/157929241

I tried different LayoutParams flags, but it didn't help. I need the touch events to pass through to the system.

"I need the touch events to pass through to the system." -- then do not have a window positioned to intercept them. An app being able to view touch events that are destined for another app is a security flaw, which is why Android continues to add barriers to such behavior.

@CommonsWare, So this is necessary. My application creates a floating menu that should respond to touches.

IMHO, a floating menu does not need "the touch events to pass through to the system".

@CommonsWare, To render the menu, a surface - a canvas - is needed. It is this canvas that is responsible for the touches.

Correct. That is your app. You need to receive the touch events in your app. What you are asking for is to also pass the events along to the underlying app ("the touch events to pass through to the system"). That is what is blocked and IMHO is not something that a floating menu needs.

@CommonWare, So how do I do it then? Because now, when the menu appears, I can control it, but I can't use the device itself. For example, if this menu just hangs there and does nothing, then I simply won't be able to use the device's screen until the menu is closed

"but I can't use the device itself" -- only cover a small portion of the screen with your floating menu. Allow the user to move the floating menu out of the way to get to things underneath it. In other words, you operate how windowed UI systems have worked for decades.

But the menu itself doesn't cover the entire screen, just a small part of it. The issue is with the Canvas, which covers the whole screen. You can't remove it.

"The issue is with the Canvas, which covers the whole screen" -- have your window be smaller than the whole screen.

I see, so there's no other way. Are there any other, easier methods?

@CommonWare, Also, I forgot to write at the very beginning that this canvas is still used to display some data during application execution, which makes resizing the canvas useless. It's not like making a separate canvas for each text.

You will need to redesign your app.

so sad situation...

Use FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH to your WindowManager.LayoutParams this may help you to capture the touch events outside
canvasLayoutParams_vi = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL 
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

try this and make sure that
targetSdkVersion 31

in your gradle file and check all the manifest permissions that are being used.

No, it didn't help me.
